# BibLaTeX doesn't seem to work with MacTex 2010

Tags: errors, biblatex, texlive, mactex

I've read good things about biblatex so I want to use it for my paper. I use MacTex 2010 on OS X  10.6.6 with Textmate. So far I've been happy with MacTex but I just can' get `biblatex` to run.

I did a `tlmgr update --all` and I've also tried `texhash` but no matter what, I can't even use the built-in styles. I tried to test `biblatex` by using "biblatex-apa": `\usepackage[bibstyle=apa.bbx]{biblatex}` but all I get is this error message:

```
 Latex Error: /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty:9654
 Package biblatex Error: Style 'apa.bbx' not found.
```

The web hasn't been able to provide any help so far, maybe you guys can.
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your loading line should read

```
\usepackage[bibstyle=apa]{biblatex}
```

*wtihout* the extension. Also, the `apa` style is not one of the core [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) ones: it is part of [`biblatex-apa`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-apa). (If you've got a fully up-to-date TeX Live 2010 you should have that, so that is not going to be the issue here.)

Comment: Wow. That's pretty bad... I was sure from the biblatex doc that I needed to include the .bbx. Thanks! It works like a charm.